# ActionScript not working when playing in Internet Explorer

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8, macromedia

I created simple space shootin game in Macromedia Professional CS6 and when i played in my desktop it is playing fine. But now, I uploaded the .swf and .fla files to my mail and downloaded them in a system where Macromedia flash CS6 is not installed. I tried opening the .swf file in Internet Explorer, all the symbols are moving as specified in the action script. But when i press space to shoot or used arrow keys to move the flight, it is not gettin any respone. Why is this problem occured? Is there a solution for this?

Comment: `Macromedia Professional CS6` - what is this mystery software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer requires user interaction (e.g. click) with the embedded SWF before it will register Keyboard Events.